# setcookie doesn't work with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, cookies

I am trying to sign in users using ajax form.

The code is very simple:

I send the form data to login.php using jquery $.post:

```
        $.post('login.php', {password: upass, username: uuser}, function(response) {
            location.reload();
        });
```

then in login.php I set the cookies:

```
        setcookie("username","$username",time()+ (1000 * 1000 * 100));
        setcookie("password","$password",time()+ (1000 * 1000 * 100));
```

but for some reasons this doesn't work, although it is working just fine on localhost.

*I tried to set the domain name but still not working
*it was working just fine before moving to vps plan from shared hosting plan (same domain different providers)

Comment: Cookies are presneted on load of the page, if you send a cookie, you need to request them from the server using a page load, i.e. *Load page sending cookies, reload page*

Comment: "this doesn't work"  _In what way_ is it not working?  Nothing you've shown above actually attempts to _use_ any cookies.

Comment: Side note: Just never do this... there is no point: `"$variable"`

Comment: Have you looked at your browsers dev tools? Network tab, to watch the ajax call go, and return, the values in the raw headers, any console errors... ?

Comment: Actually this is just a part of a big script. When I said it is not working I meant it doesn't get stored in the browser cookies and $_COOKIE[$cookie_name] doesn't work.

Comment: thanks @IncredibleHat for the side not, but the thing is it is a big script that I am just working on I haven't built it from scratch myself. Actually I am just making some modifications and one of them is to change the server.

Comment: Looking into the browser dev tools (specifically network tab), and checking the raw headers of the response from the ajax .post to login.php might shed some light if the setcookie is happening (or it may give you an error about cross domain or something else). Also to note, if you ever do `setcookie` and need to subsequently use `$_COOKIE['cookiename']` in the same execution, you need to also explicitly set `$_COOKIE['cookiename'] = $cookievalue;` when you do the `setcookie()`.

Comment: Adding the path to `setcookie()` might be helpful. I've read things people having issues when they don't set a path. I've always set at least `'/'`, so I do not know first hand if omitting it entirely may cause issues with the browser actually setting the cookie from the header return.

Comment: I have tried to set the cookie path but still the same problem.

Comment: The thing is I can see no errors in the network tab

Comment: Since this is part of a larger script with many working parts, have you tried to just setup a basic bare-bones html page that ajax's a php script whose only job is to set a cookie with a basic echo return? To see if just that works or not? Might be worth a shot, to eliminate as many other variables as possible to figure out the sole cause of why no cookies are coming through on an ajax call.

Comment: Thanks a lot I will try that